# how to read image into tensor from url directly

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow, so please bear with me.

I want to convert the `read_tensor_from_image_file` function from tensorflow tutorial to be able to read a image from url.

So instead of passing in the file location as `file_name`, I can pass in a url as file_name such as `https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-500kb.jpg`, and do the same resizing and converts it to an nparray of the same dimension. I'm hoping to do this without having to first save the image locally if possible.

But I'm not sure how to read the image into the format that the `tf.image.decode_jpeg` expects.

I have tried to read the image into bytes and pass it to `tf.read`_file and `tf.image` but can't get it to work.

```
response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
def read_tensor_from_image_file(
        file_name, input_height=299, input_width=299, input_mean=0,
        input_std=255
):
    input_name = "file_reader"
    file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
    if file_name.endswith(".png"):
        image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(
            file_reader, channels=3, name="png_reader")
    elif file_name.endswith(".gif"):
        image_reader = tf.squeeze(
            tf.image.decode_gif(file_reader, name="gif_reader"))
    elif file_name.endswith(".bmp"):
        image_reader = tf.image.decode_bmp(file_reader, name="bmp_reader")
    else:
        image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(
            file_reader, channels=3, name="jpeg_reader")
    float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
    dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0)
    resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander,
                                       [input_height, input_width])
    normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
    sess = tf.Session()
    result = sess.run(normalized)

    return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `response.content` directly with `tf.image.decode_jpeg`. The following code proves that you will get the same array:

```
import numpy as np
import requests
import tensorflow as tf


def read_tensor_from_image_url(url,
                               input_height=299,
                               input_width=299,
                               input_mean=0,
                               input_std=255):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(
        requests.get(url).content, channels=3, name="jpeg_reader")
    float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
    dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0)
    resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
    normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        return sess.run(normalized)


def read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                                input_height=299,
                                input_width=299,
                                input_mean=0,
                                input_std=255):
    input_name = "file_reader"
    file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(
        file_reader, channels=3, name="jpeg_reader")
    float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
    dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0)
    resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
    normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        return sess.run(normalized)


local_img = read_tensor_from_image_file(
    r'Sample-jpg-image-500kb.jpg'
)
online_img = read_tensor_from_image_url(
    r'https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-500kb.jpg'
)
print(np.all(local_img == online_img))
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: How to load video from url into tensor model directly?